# open a facebook page -is it true?

Tags: objective-c

I
have read everywhere so many different things about opening the facebook app from another app, and some says its not official and can be changed ,some say its ok,

but anyway it doesnt work for me (and for many others-with broken pages)

i use :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://pages/MY-APP-PAGE"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

its open the facebook app, but with a white page. on my mac- this link is working.

so, is this thing is real ?

Comment: anyone ???? its just not working !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

since i KNOW many people know how to do that , and are not answering,
well , thats how its done :

```
NSURL *fanPageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/PAGE ID"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:fanPageURL];
```

Where PAGE ID is the long id number at the end of your facebook page .

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for this answer.

To support more users, I used this one:

```
    NSURL *nsurl = [ [ NSURL alloc ] initWithString: @"fb://profile/463560897057026" ];
    if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:nsurl])
        nsurl = [ [ NSURL alloc ] initWithString: @"http://www.facebook.com/SmileyGames" ];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:nsurl];
```